# CJK unicode characters output from `wine reg query` displayed on terminal are fine. But they become question marks after pipe

Tags: linux, command-line, unicode, wine, pipe

When I run `wine reg query 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Akelsoft\AkelPad\Recent'` on my machine, the output is fine and contains something like `file0    REG_MULTI_SZ    Z:\home\x\怎.txt` on my terminal.

But if I run `wine reg query 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Akelsoft\AkelPad\Recent' | tee out.txt` then I noticed each CJK unicode character becomes one `?` character. (Both out.txt and terminal output are corrupted.)

Like `file0    REG_MULTI_SZ    Z:\home\x\?.txt`

(BTW I tried `wine reg query 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Akelsoft\AkelPad\Recent' | tac`. Also got `?` on terminal.)

(BTW I tried `wine reg query 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Akelsoft\AkelPad\Recent' > out.txt`. Also got `?` in the file.)

(Mysterious phenomena. Not sure if it's caused by something `wine` did incorrectly. Maybe it uses `isatty` and acts differently when stdout is pipe)

Is there an easy way (command line) to save output to a file while preserving the original text?